# Angular Material mat-select reuse mat-option

Tags: angular, performance, angular-material

We have a large form in our Angular 9 app, with +30 select boxes, with +50 options in each of them. In the current version, the
selects are just implemented directly in the html, where the following `<mat-form-field>` is just copy-pasted +30 times.

The problem is that the initiation of the `mat-optgroup` i relatively slow, and therefore introduce a huge performance lack
with +30 selects to be initiated individually!

All `mat-select` uses the same `mat-optgroup` so we are looking for a solution where the `mat-optgroup` is initiated once
and reused in all selects?

We have tried a solution where `mat-optgroup` are taken from `ng-template` but without success. A way to go could be the
use of `ng-content` but we haven't succeeded an implementation. A working example with `ng-content` would
be a huge help to see, or other suggestions for performance improvements are very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="account">
        <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of groupedAccount" [label]="group.name">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let account of group.accounts" [disabled]="account.disabled" [value]="account">
                {{ account.number }} - {{ account.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Minimum reproduction, which only show the loading time, which is even longer in the real app, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eax4xk

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look Angular Material tabs

Angular Material tabs organize content into separate views where only one view can be visible at a time.

...Lazy Loading
By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated.

Hope this will help

[Lazy Loading](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, It will sort the problem partly, since the load time is distributed, but due to our setup we will have 22 selects in one group. So the lazy rendering time is also relatively long. So I'm still hoping for some solution where the options are created once.

Comment: If you can put the code running in stackblitz.com it will help us figure what the problem is

Comment: I have added at Stackblitz example, this is not the real app but a minimum example of the problem, showing the load time when expanding the group.

Comment: I think you are using ng-template in wrong way
   try this


<ng-template matExpansionPanelContent #myTemplate>
 <mat-label>Salg af varer m/moms</mat-label>
 <mat-select required [compareWith]="compareObj" name="_var" appearance="fill">
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of groupedAccount" [label]="group.name">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let account of group.accounts" [disabled]="account.disabled" [value]="account">
    {{ account.number }} - {{ account.name }}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
 </mat-select>
</ng-template>

Comment: and use this in instead of each control

 <mat-form-field class="w-100">
   <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate" ></ng-template>
  </mat-form-field>